# creating equiangular HDRI of my own scene

Tags: workflow

I have created a room in an arch viz project.  It has no windows.  Currently I'm using a studio light HDRI setup for lighting.

I'm rendering out what I will call backplates and then **separately** rendering out some animations of forground characters and objects, and then compositing them together with the backplate.

Here is my problem.   One of the objects I am rendering separately is all chrome, so it is now reflecting only the studio lights of the current HDRI. But I need it to reflect my actual room.  So I would like to create a quick and dirty HDRI equiangular map of my actual room.

-The backplate renders is 1280 x 720px.
-I am using Cycles

Can anyone provide me a detailed workflow on how to properly create my HDRI map within Blender? Please also tell me what size it should be.

Comment: I actually have done this before. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...  I checked out the other answer that was previously posted.